# How to add a header to the top of a tableview and to every section

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to add a header to the top of a tableview as well as a header to the top of every section in the tableview?

An example would be an image at the top of the tableview and then a row heading label at the top of every section.

Comment: Do you want this image to scroll with the table or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a header for the first section that contains your standard header as well as the header that you want for the top of your tableView. Configure the UITableViewDelegate to return the top header only for the first section, otherwise use the standard header.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(section == 0) {
        MyTopHeader *header = [[MyTopHeader alloc] init];
        return header;
    }
    else {
        MySectionHeader *header = [[MySectionHeader alloc] init];
        return header;
    }
}
```

You will probably need to customize the height as well.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(section == 0) {
        return 150.0f; //top header height
    }
    else {
        return 70.0f; // section header height
    }
}
```